# How to change to FetchType.Eager with Criteria or Profiles. when using FetchMode.SELECT

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using Version 4.2 of hibernate.

I have a normal relation that is:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "xxx")
```

How do i change this programmatically to `FetchType.EAGER`?

if i use `@FetchProfile` with `FetchMode.JOIN` i change the behavior of how the SQL will look, since i want to keep that it do aa `FetchMode.Select` instead of joining.

is this possible?

But i want it to do the Selects Eagerly, if i use `FetchType.EAGER` directly on my entity and use a `fetchprofile` with `FetchMode.Select` it works but i don't want it to be eager all the time.

Comment: You mean setting the profile dynamically?. check this http://blog.frankel.ch/hibernate-hard-facts-part-6

Comment: I know how to activte a profile, i want to know how to make an relation Eager but with FetchMode.Select